# fbConnect for iphone - Posting photos to news feed and automating a link to itunes app store

Tags: iphone, sdk, photo, fbconnect

is there a way to make a fbConnection for iphone within an app environment on the iphone and post a Photo to your FB newsfeed after a secure login without leaving the iphone app environment?

Answer (score 1):

yes. Facebook connect is available for iPhone and iTunes URLs are just URLs.

Comment: hey roger, thanks for the reply. i guess my question was surrounding the function of: 1. connecting to FB from the your iPhone App enivironemt without leaving 2. Posting a photo from your App library 3. Automating a link that says "This photo was taken from the "PhotoApp" - available at iTunes Store

Answer (score 0):

ShareKit offers you all of the above and more - Login without leaving the app, upload text/links/photos direct to your wall, support many social networks and more!

http://www.getsharekit.com/

Comment: I was originally using sharekit (which is awesome for what it does!), but was having trouble separating out their object hierarchy and figuring out how to do my custom feed posting without all their action-sheet stuff in between.  Do you have a pointer to a good example/tute for this?  Thanks!